# Blank screen instead map api v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I have spent 3 days, but can't find solution...
When I launch map on a device with android 2.2 I have blank screen with zoom-buttons. Logcat shows the error message "**E/copybit: Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)**".

The google-play-services_lib and android-support-v4 were added.

My AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.testmap"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<permission
        android:name="com.testmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.testmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:allowBackup="true"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon_iphone">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

</application>
```

Fragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/mapViewMain"
              android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: any Logcat hint? Perhaps an error in Google authentication?

Comment: @Rob013 no, only it : "E/copybit: Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)".

Comment: @whisperofblood have you found the cause? I think I'm dealing with the same issue. App works fine in 2.3, but not 2.2 (have tried on only one 2.2 device)

Comment: @whisperofblood FYI checking answer to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768681/google-maps-v2-shows-blank-screen-on-android-2-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is caused for sdk version.Try with upper sdk of 13.I use same thing at android 4.0(sdk 14).
So if you change your

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8">
```

to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
```

I think it will work.
**EDIT :**
You are trying to use fragments on an API Level 8 device. So switch to **FragmentActivity** and **SupportMapFragment**.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

}
```

To get the map use..

```
   FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
    = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
```

Comment: Thank you, but if change the version of sdk then I won't can launch it on android API 8(2.2). @ridoy

Comment: If you want to launch it on android 2.2 then i will suggest you to use Google map api v1 instead of v2.Because v2 needs minsdkVersion as 14.

Comment: no, V2 works with 2.2 and higer. Just need to add android-support-v4 in your project.

Comment: @Yume117 and what is supported, then?

Answer (score 0):

To use `Google Maps API V2` in Android version prior to `API 12`, you will need to use the `android-suppor`t library for backwards fragments compatibility. In addition you will need to use a `FragmentAcitivity` as been already said and a `SupportMapFragment` as you already did.

I will suggest you yo go over this blog post I wrote that will help you to integrate those components in your application and make your map work:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

In addition I think that your problem can be caused by a bad produce of the API key, take a look at this blog post as well and see that you did all the steps correctly:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)